# How to remove arrow on tooltip from bokeh plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

Is there a way to remove the little black pointer arrow that is on the tooltip (indicating the position of the mouse when the `point_policy='follow_mouse'`)?
Any help appreciated

[image]

Comment: Do not know if it is possible without modifying bokeh source code. You can set `hover.attachment = None` but it will disable the point policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [`.show_arrow`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html?highlight=hovertool#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.show_arrow)  to False. on the hover tool.

Answer (score 2):

As of Bokeh **0.12.2**, there is in option for that:

```
hover.show_arrow = False
```

This is a complete example, taken from the [official documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/quickstart.html#getting-started):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
#

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool


def main():
    # prepare some data
    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

    # output to static HTML file
    output_file("lines.html")

    # create a new plot with a title and axis labels
    p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y', tools='hover')

    # add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
    p.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

    # hover
    hover = p.select_one(HoverTool)
    hover.point_policy = "follow_mouse"
    hover.tooltips = [
        ("Name", "@name"),
        ("Unemployment rate)", "@rate%"),
        ("(Long, Lat)", "($x, $y)"),
    ]
    # disable tooltip arrow
    hover.show_arrow = False

    # show the results
    show(p)

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

---

*(For history)*

As bigreddot said, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4906) and I made a [patch](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/4907) to disable the arrow. If accepted, you will be able to disable the arrow with:

```
hover.show_arrow = False
```